# radio button set not changing

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, radio-button, webkit

I'm having a bit of trouble with a set of 2 radio buttons, that in Chrome, will not change state regardless of using the mouse or using the keyboard.

This is the HTML:

```html
<!-- Dialog Boxes -->
    <section class="add-movie-dialog">
        <section class="dialog-box">
            <form class="dialog-container" name="add-movie-dialog-form" action="">
                <header class="dialog-title">
                    New movie.
                </header>
                <section class="dialog-content">
                    <p>
                        Add a new movie to the library:
                    </p>
                    <input type="radio" name="add_option" value="file" checked="checked" />by selecting a file...
                    <br />
                    <input type="radio" name="add_option" value="empty" /> empty entry...
                </section>
            </form>
        </section>
    </section>
```

This is the CSS (infact less but close enough):

```
    .add-movie-dialog {
    #mixin.flex-container( column, center, stretch, nowrap );
    background: fadeout( @black, 50% );
    height: 100%;
    left: 0px;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    .dialog-box {
        #mixin.flex-container( column, flex-start, center, nowrap );
        background: @darkgrey;
        padding: 2em;
        .dialog-container {
            width: 66%;
            .dialog-title{
                #mixin.font( x-large );
                padding-bottom: 1em;
            }
            .dialog-content{
                letter-spacing: 0.1em;
                padding-bottom: 1em;
                & > p {
                    padding-bottom: 10px;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is an image of it:

[sample image](http://bayimg.com/OajAiAAEo)

Now, the highlighted radio button will not change to "empty entry" using either mouse or keyboard and I'm stumped as to why, as afaik the code is valid and should work (unless I'm missing something here).

Comment: I just hosted your HTML and CSS in a quick jsFiddle.net and it worked fine - I could click and select either radio button with no issues. Maybe you can host a more complete, failing, sample in jsFiddle for us to see the problem

Comment: Seems I had left some old javascript in the JS file I was using, which messed with the selections, but after removing the offending JS block, it righted itself.

Cheers though.